# Maven dependencies plugin not copying transitive dependencies?

Tags: maven

I'm aware that the maven dependencies plugin is supposed to copy transitive dependencies by default. However, when I try this in this in this example, only the explicitly specified jar is copied:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>consoleApp</artifactId>
    <groupId>me.wundrian</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>consoleApp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mavenCentral</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-local-dynamodb</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.16.0</version>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamoDBLocal</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

A `mvn compile && ls target/lib` produces this output:

```
DynamoDBLocal-1.16.0.jar
```

I'm specifically looking for the libsqlite4java* dependencies the DynamoDBLocal pom specifies as runtime dependencies.

Comment: The first step is to use the `copy-dependencies` goal instead...The question is why you copy deps into a lib directory ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Uh, that's embarrassing. Indeed, `copy-dependencies` works just fine.. well, sort of. I'm still hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-454 but I can work around that by explicitly specifying the dependency and the transitive artificats I want.
The reason I need this is that DynamoDBLocal depends on libsqlite4java which brings in native libraries that are I need in _some_ configurations of the build but not in all. 
Want to make your comment into an answer?